# VB.NET ListView/ListBox Checked item in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, listbox

How do I simply add a checked (or unchecked) item in a `listview` (or a `listbox`) ?

I've searched for a long time but I always find topics on Windows Forms about `CheckedListBox` objects and `ListView.Checked` properties that don't seem to exist in WPF.

I succeeded in populating the list with some groups from an active directory, but I don't know how to show them with a simple check (or hide them).

Do I need to import some references?

I'm working with VB.NET with Visual Studio Express 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox`:

```
         <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                              Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But how do i do it in vb.net? I need to dynamically populate de listbox (or listview) with each group returns by request from ActiveDirectory. Have you got an ideo of the vb.net code ?

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection(of T)` as it's `ItemsSource`. I can't tell you anything else without having more details. Post another question with that if you need.

Comment: So,I create a WPF Window with a lot of objets.
One of those is declared like this with VisualStudio in XAML :
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="251" Margin="412,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
With the vb.net code, when a user is selected, the list of available groups is displayed in the ListBox :
For Each usrGroupe In fGetMember("OU=" + Tab(i, 0), usrFiltre) 'fGetMember returns a SearchResultCollection wich contains all groups
 ListBox.Items.Add(usrGroupe.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("cn").Value) 'it works
Next

Comment: I need to have checkboxes before each group listed in the ListBox (or ListView) but i don't know how...

After this, when the final-user click on a button it will affect the selected user to the checked groups...

Thx

Comment: Dude, you need to learn XAML, and MVVM. You don't `ListBox.Items.Add()` in WPF. you BIND the ListBox's `ItemsSource` to something in the ViewModel. WPF is not winforms, you must learn the appropiate development patterns before you can use it. Also, I have no idea what you mean by `"declared like this with VisualStudio in XAML"`. Add the `ItemTemplate` part of the XAML I posted in order to get CheckBoxes before each item.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... VisualStudio is an application wich do the XAML job himself and is easy to use for beginners like me. There is no "ItemTemplate" in the XAML code so i think it's time for me to learn more about it. If you've got some links ^^

Comment: Dude... I know what Visual Studio is... you shouldn't be using the designer in WPF. you need to learn XAML, and MVVM.

Comment: Yep... i'm trying to ^^ All sources i find seems to be for c#. Maybe i need to learn this language too ... :(

Comment: Exactly. VB.Net is, IMO, an intermediate step for VB6 developers coming into .Net. But then the real stuff is done in C#. It happened to me as well, I used to code in VB6, then jumped into .Net, but I was not used to the C# syntax, so I used VB.Net, then I learned the C# syntax in the end.

Comment: lol...so at least it'sbetter to begin in c# to be familiar with it from the beginning...